# Probability distribution that is approximately binomial but favors pairing of results.

Tags: probability, statistics

Is there a well-studied distribution that is approximately binomial, but in which results where the successes of the experiment come in pairs are slightly more favored?

The application is in competitive video games there is ranked matchmaking that places players on teams based on a rank score. Because the game takes quite a few matches to decide an appropriate rank, some players will make new accounts to try to game the system and play in a lower rank (for whatever reason). These are typically referred to as "smurfs."

I am interested in the distribution of the number of such players. A binomial distribution seems reasonable, however since players have the option of looking for a match in groups, most frequently as duos, I think that is skewing the results to favor even numbers.

[image: Blue histogram represents the number of smurfs across 53 games. Red line represents a binomial fitted to the maximum number of smurfs and the sample probability of a player being a smurf]

It seems to be the case that the number of smurfs favors even numbers. I don't really know enough about power analysis to say whether it does so in a "significant" way given my sample size (data comes from 53 games of Overwatch although I am curious about this phenomenon in other games as well).

I guess I should say, I'm curious if there is a better way of conducting this experiment to achieve a more robust result? Should I be batching the games or something?

Comment: What about just using the discrete probability distribution with support $0,1,2\ldots,7$ (or whatever the maximum rank is) and the probability of each rank just equal to the observed relative frequency? Not sure what you are planning to do with it, but this gives you a well-defined probability distribution and you can do whatever calculations you want with it (mean, variance etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test whether even ranks indeed occur statistically significantly more frequently using a statistical test. Here is one way to do it (using a binomial test).

Let $E$ be a random variable that takes on value 1, if the rank is even, and 0 if not. Then, E must follow a Bernoulli-distribution with some success probability $p\in[0,1]$. Our null hypothesis is that even and odd ranks are equally likely ($p=0.5$). The alternative hypothesis is that even ranks  occur with a higher probability ($p>0.5$). The test statistic is the number of even ranks observed in the sample. It follows a binomial distribution with parameter $n$ (sample size, total number of accounts in your data) and $p=0.5$ under the null hypothesis. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test) for an explanation how the test works and how to implement it.